# ShellexecuteEx fails with ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, shellexecute, windows-shell

I'm developing a network redirector using RDBSS.

In our network redirector volume, a executable file which is packed from [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)(Open source packer) can not be run.
When we do double-click the file in Windows Explorer, the Explorer shows this messagebox.

[image]

It works well on 32bit Windows. Only 64bit Windows is problem.
I guess it is related with npdll or MUP.
We have implemented npdll, and I thought it doesn't have any bug now. - Of course we also have npdll 64bit version.
Other executable files and any files work well for both 32 and 64OS.

If we run this file in 64bit Windows SMB volume, it runs fine.
So, I'm pretty sure some our codes have a bug.(npdll or redirector driver)

Could you guess anything about this?

P.S Is there a good document describing how MUP works? If you know, let me know please.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try using Sysinternals Process Monitor (with an appropriate filter). It may tell you what is failing.

Comment: Of course I tried. I love the tool. In this case, however, PM doesn't tell me anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

The other executables which work, are they 64-bit or 32-bit?

If only 32-bit processes (like InnoSetup) fail, could it be that you need to install both the 64- and 32-bit versions of your DLL on x64 systems? That's required for some DLL types (e.g. video codecs) if you want their functionality to be available to all programs, but I'm not familiar with RDBSS and thus don't know if it applies in this case.